# перевызов событий?

Tags: c#

всем привет, имеется данный пример:

```
 public delegate void EventDelegate();

public class MyClass
{
    public event EventDelegate myEvent = null;

    public void InvokeEvent()
    {
        myEvent.Invoke();
    }
}

class Program
{
    // Методы обработчики события.

    static private void Handler1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Обработчик события 1");
    }

    static private void Handler2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Обработчик события 2");
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        MyClass instance = new MyClass(); 

        // Присоединение обработчиков событий. (Подписка на событие)
        instance.myEvent += new EventDelegate(Handler1);
        instance.myEvent += Handler2;

        // Метод который вызывает событие.
        instance.InvokeEvent();

        Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 20));

        // Открепляем Handler2().
        instance.myEvent -= new EventDelegate(Handler2);

        instance.InvokeEvent();

        // Delay.
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Зачем тут метод InvokeEvent, который перевызывает событие myEvent?

Зачем вообще перевызывать событие? Почему не вызвать его "напрямую" - как метод?

Comment: _Почему не вызвать его "напрямую" - как метод?_ где именно?

Comment: @Grundy `instance.myEvent.Invoke();` вместо `instance.InvokeEvent();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому, что вы не можете снаружи класса вызвать event, у вас это просто не скомпилируется. Снаружи класса можно только подписаться на event или отписаться от него.

Кстати, у вас неправильно вызывается event: в случае, если подписчиков нет, ваш вызов грохнется. Пишите так:

```
myEvent?.Invoke();
```

Comment: по уму там должно быть свойство типа делегата события и встроенная подписка на обработчик по умолчанию, например пустой, чтобы не шаманить с проверками на пустоту делегата и не бояться записи пользователем null в делегат.

Comment: @rdorn: На мой вкус, это слишком много свободы пользователю. А если он захочет отписать то, что не подписывал сам? Это всё равно, что открыть приватные поля. Пусть лучше будет так, с защитой.

Comment: эм.. а как он отпишется от того на что не подписывался? ладно, положу в свой ответ демку того о чем говорю, там и обсудим =)

Comment: @rdorn: Например, присвоит `null` свойству.

Comment: готово, может найдутся замечания

Comment: @rdorn: А, теперь понял. Не знаю, стоит ли предохраняться от `+= null`, вроде никто этого не делает. Интересно, что при этом произошло бы. Может быть, если передать `null`, ничего не упадёт?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43225/discussion-between-rdorn-and-vladd).

Answer (score 2):

События предназначены для вызова внутри класса в котором они определены, для информирования подписчиков о том, что событие таки произошло. Метод `instance.InvokeEvent();` нужен для имитации срабатывания события, не более. Про то, почему вызов делается именно так, **@VladD** уже написал.

Про фрагмент кода:

```
// Присоединение обработчиков событий. (Подписка на событие)
instance.myEvent += new EventDelegate(Handler1);
instance.myEvent += Handler2;

// Метод который вызывает событие.
instance.InvokeEvent();
```

Этот фрагмент демонстрирует, что если на событие подписалось более одного обработчика, при срабатывании события вызваны будут все подписавшиеся. При этом порядок вызова обработчиков не гарантируется, хотя в большинстве случаев вызов происходит в порядке подписки, рассчитывать на это нельзя даже в однопоточной программе без асинхронных действий.

```
// Открепляем Handler2().
instance.myEvent -= new EventDelegate(Handler2);

instance.InvokeEvent();
```

Далее нам предлагают отписаться от события и вызвать его еще раз, тем самым демонстрируя, что после отписки, обработчик который мы отписали от события не будет вызван. Именно для этого, метод имитации события вызывается второй раз.

На этом собственно все. Больше про оторванный от контекста кусок кода сказать нечего. Если рассматривать данный фрагмент как демонстрацию работы с multycast делегатами, то пример не самый лучший и практически ни чего полезного не демонстрирует, кроме небезопасного кода, который свалится с исключением при любом неловком движении.

Ну и напоследок, как все таки сделать событие безопасным для использования пользователем с произвольной кривизной рук и логики (критика принимается)

```
public class MyClass
{
    private void _DefaultHandler() { }

    private event EventDelegate _myEvent += _DefaultHandler;

    public event EventDelegate MyEvent
    {
        add { _myEvent += value; }
        remove { _myEvent -= value; }
    }
}
```

Короткий синтаксис как для обычных автоматических свойств `SomeProperty{get; set;}` для событий пока недоступен, хотя по идее возможен для реализации.

И чуть более сложный пример из документации на [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/8843a9ch(v=vs.110).aspx)